# Passing string variables to a jquery code inside a php class

Tags: php, jquery, class, variables

I am almost new with jquery. I have a PHP class for a calender, in which a function returns a part of jquery code. In fact, I wan to disable specific dates in a calnder, and these dates are different for various database queries. I can pass the variable, and in the source code in IE, I see the variable like this: $(#datepicker1).datepicker, but when it is static, it looks like $("#datepicker1").datepicker. Although in the first style, the variable type is string, it does not understand that it is an html tag ID, and it does not apply the method on that Tag. 
This is the main function inside the PHP class:

```
function createCal($month, $day, $id)
    {

        //echo('#'.($this->datePickerID));
        $ids=("#datepicker".$id);
        echo($ids);
        return<<<html
<script>
$(function() {
    //-----------------------------------
    $($ids).datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            //alert(date.getDate());
            if (date.getDay()==5 ||( date.getMonth()==$month && date.getDate() == $day))
                return [false, '', 'weekends'];
            return [true];
        }
    });


});
```

and this is source code from IE

```
<script>
$(function() {
    //-----------------------------------

    $(#datepicker1).datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            //alert(date.getDate());
            if (date.getDay()==5 ||( date.getMonth()==0 && date.getDate() == 26))
                return [false, '', 'weekends'];
            return [true];
        }
    });


});
</script>
<p class='ui-widget-content'>

    date:
    <input type="text" id="datepicker1" />
</p>
```

Comment: use JSON to pass your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the ID:

```
$('$ids').datepicker({
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved, but it is a variable, is it a JS syntax to put a variable which is string inside quotes again?

Comment: The PHP value doesn't have quotes around it, so you have to add them.